# How to pass a list to a WCF service with PowerShell

Tags: c#, list, wcf, powershell

- I need to built a scheduled task for posting once per day, a log
  about users session information (log in/log off/session lock/session
  unlock...). I have created a WCF service, a database, and functions
  for getting theses infos. The last step is to built a PowerShell
  script for posting to the service, this log, from users pc's.
- In my console application I'm using ConfigItem dataclass for my list and then I pass this List with the two otjers string arguments to service. I don't understand how I could do the same thing in the PS script, using the same arguments and post them to the service.

My service method:

```
public void RecordActivity(string user, string pc, List<ConfigItem> act)
        {
            var USR = new Users() { UserName = user };
            var PC = new Pc() { PcName = pc };
            act.ToList().ForEach(p =>
            {
                int id = (from t in context.Activity where t.ActivityName==p.Activity select t.ActivityId).SingleOrDefault(); 
                var RF = new AuditActivity() { Date = p.Date,ActivityId=id};
                USR.AuditActivity.Add(RF);
                PC.AuditActivity.Add(RF);
                context.Set<Pc>().Add(PC);
                context.Set<Users>().Add(USR);
            });
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Data class in service :

```
[DataContract]
public class ConfigItem
{
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Activity { get; set; }
}
```

Function to get users informations and post them in service (working in a console app)

```
    AuditServiceTestClient sve = new AuditServiceTestClient();
    string machine = Environment.MachineName;
    string userName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
    List<ConfigItem> cfg = new List<ConfigItem>();
    const char fieldSeparator = ';';
    string filePath = @"h:\csv\Activity.csv";
    using (StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        while (!SR.EndOfStream) 
        {
        var CSValues = SR.ReadLine().Split(fieldSeparator);
        ConfigItem c = new ConfigItem();
        c.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(CSValues[0]);
        c.Activity = CSValues[1];
        cfg.Add(c);
        }
   }
   sve.RecordActivity(userName, machine, cfg);
```

My PowerShell script :

```
$WebSvcURL= “http://xxx/AuditServiceTest.svc”

#Create the Web Service Proxy Object
$proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $WebSvcURL -Namespace ExportTool  -Class Program -UseDefaultCredential

$proxy
Write-host -ForegroundColor DarkBlue ===successfullyconnected to the WCF Web Service $proxy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where your `ConfigItem` comes from, so `New-Object`'s invocations may differ:

```
$WebSvcURL = 'http://xxx/AuditServiceTest.svc'

#Create the Web Service Proxy Object
$proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $WebSvcURL -Namespace ExportTool  -Class Program -UseDefaultCredential

# Get machine and user name
$userName = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
$machine = [System.Environment]::MachineName

# Create new list of ConfigItems
$cfg = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.Generic.List``1[ConfigItem]

# Import CSV, add values to list of ConfigItems
Import-Csv -Path 'h:\csv\Activity.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    # Create new ConfigItem
    $item = New-Object -TypeName ConfigItem

    # Set properties
    $item.Date = $_.Date
    $item.Activity = $_.Activity

    # add item to list
    $cfg.Add($item)
}

# Call service method
$proxy.RecordActivity($userName, $machine, $cfg)
```

#### References

- [Powershell Generic Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184476/powershell-generic-collections)

Comment: ConfigItem is a class created in my WCF service. WCF service method is called, but list is empty

Comment: @mrplume Could you post returned serialized objects from console app and PS script? Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611187/using-complex-objects-via-a-web-service-from-powershell

Comment: Hum... I'n not returning serialized objects from console, I post only values via the service. For return, I'm using a MVC application

Comment: With the creation of a custom class "ConfigItem" I get an error. This error helps me to get correct adress to call my ConfigItem on the service. So with 'code'System.Collections.Generic.List``1[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1ost_xxx_AuditServiceTest_svc.ConfigItem] it's working. Thanks.