# Powershell New-WebServiceProxy - how to call WCF service

Tags: wcf, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to call a WCF service from PowerShell.

This is what I have so far based on a few misc example I found on the web:

```
# Create the WebSvcURL variable and pass the WSDL URL
$WebSvcURL= “http://localhost/DEMO/SetPassKey/SetPassKey_Logic_SetPassKeyWebService_SetPassKeyWCF.svc?wsdl“

#Create the Web Service Proxy Object

#$serviceProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $WebSvcURL -Namespace "http://Sample.SetPassKey.Logic" -Class Program -UseDefaultCredential
$serviceProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $WebSvcURL -UseDefaultCredential

# Create Request Object
$namespace = $serviceProxy.getType().namespace
write-host "Namespace=$namespace"
$req  = New-Object ($namespace + "/SetPassKeyOrchWebRequest")  
$resp = New-Object ($namespace + "/SetPassKeyOrchWebResponse")  

$req.NewPassKey = "TEST"    # <--- PUT YOUR NEW PASSWORD HERE 

$resp = $serviceProxy.SetPassKey($req) 

$resp
```

I'm confused on a few things:

1. If and when I need to include the -Namespace and -Class parameters on the. Since it looks at the WSDL, I don't understand why it needs the -Namespace and -Class.
2. How to construct the request/response objects
3. Should the URL be the actual URL of the web service or should it include the ?wsdl suffix

UPDATE:
I found this [blog](https://sarafian.github.io/amadeus/2019/06/28/powershell-soap-proxy-new-webserviceproxy.html) which states:

> The -Namespace parameter is optional and when not
> specified then it gets a random value from the cmdlet.

I was thinking it was an XML Namespace, but it's a .NET framework namespace.

```
# Create the WebSvcURL variable and pass the WSDL URL
$WebSvcURL= “http://localhost/DEMO/SetPassKey/SetPassKey_Logic_SetPassKeyWebService_SetPassKeyWCF.svc?wsdl“

#Create the Web Service Proxy Object

$serviceProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $WebSvcURL -UseDefaultCredential -Namespace "MyNamespace" -Class Program 

# Create Request Object
$req  = New-Object ("MyNamespace.SetPassKeyOrchWebRequest")  
$resp = New-Object ("MyNamespace.SetPassKeyOrchWebResponse")  

$req.NewPassKey = "TEST"    # <--- PUT YOUR NEW PASSWORD HERE 

$resp = $serviceProxy.SetPassKey($req) 

$resp
```

Now I get this error:
Exception calling "SetPassKey" with "1" argument(s): "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a
receive."

The webservice can be called by a C# console program, so I know it works. Just need to call it from PowerShell.

Comment: The difference between whether there is a wsdl suffix is that wsdl can obtain and call metadata, which can be used to create client proxy classes. This is the official document on how to use PowerShell to call WCFService: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-webserviceproxy?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Of course I've been to that page.  It gives example 1 without class/namespace, and example 2 with class/namespace.  One of my questions is why would I need class/namespace if I have the WSDL?

Comment: @TheobaldDu That page also fails to show how to build a request/response object; their example is just using simple types.

Answer (score 1):

I tried some things, and finally got it to work.
I did change my binding from WCF-WSHttp to WCF-BasicHttp.

I also followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611187/using-complex-objects-via-a-web-service-from-powershell), which said they only got it working by using the auto-generated namespace.

One of my issues originally was using "/" instead of "." as the separator between the namespace and the web request/response class names.

I'm still confused by the -namespace and -class parameters, as the post above said it only got the process working by using the autogenerated namespace (which happens when you omit the -namespace parm).

My code ended up something like this:

```
# Create the WebSvcURL variable and pass the WSDL URL
$WebSvcURL= “http://localhost/DEMO/SetPassKey/SetPassKey_Logic_SetPassKeyWebService_SetPassKeyWCF.svc?wsdl“

#Create the Web Service Proxy Object
 $serviceProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $WebSvcURL -UseDefaultCredential

$autoGenNamespace = $serviceProxy.getType().namespace
write-host "Namespace=$namespace"
$req  = New-Object ($autoGenNamespace + ".SetPassKeyOrchWebRequest")  
$resp = New-Object ($autoGenNamespace + ".SetPassKeyOrchWebResponse")  

$req.NewPassKey = "TEST"    # <--- PUT YOUR NEW PASSWORD HERE 

$req.NewPassKey = "TEST"      # <--- PUT YOUR NEW PASSWORD HERE 
Write-Host "Request:"
Write-Host ($req | Format-Table | Out-String)

Write-Host "About to call WebService" 
$resp = $serviceProxy.SetPassKey($req) 


Write-Host "Response:"
Write-Host ($resp | Format-Table | Out-String)
```

NOTE: Just putting the variable name without the write-host statement was causing things to come out in a different sequence.  The FormatTable was still truncating some fields, so I will list each return string in my $resp separately.