# PowerShell WCF "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."

Tags: wcf, powershell-4.0

I have a C# that calls a WCF webservice and it's working fine, so we know the webservice works and that it can be called.

I'm now trying to call same WCF webservice from Powershell, as below, and getting the error:

```
 "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a 
receive."
```

The web service does some logging, and I don't see any of it when trying the PowerShell call.

```
# Create the WebSvcURL variable and pass the WSDL URL
$WebSvcURL= “http://localhost/DEMO/SetPassKey/SetPassKey_Logic_SetPassKeyWebService_SetPassKeyWCF.svc?wsdl“

#Create the Web Service Proxy Object

$serviceProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $WebSvcURL -UseDefaultCredential -Namespace "MyNamespace" -Class Program 

# Create Request Object
$req  = New-Object ("MyNamespace.SetPassKeyOrchWebRequest")  
$resp = New-Object ("MyNamespace.SetPassKeyOrchWebResponse")  

$req.NewPassKey = "TEST"    # <--- PUT YOUR NEW PASSWORD HERE 
$req   #  show the value is okay in the WebRequestobject 

$resp = $serviceProxy.SetPassKey($req) 

$resp  # show the response object
```

My related question was: [Powershell New-WebServiceProxy - how to call WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65692957/powershell-new-webserviceproxy-how-to-call-wcf-service).  When I got past that, I started getting the error above.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by using the WCF-BasicHTTP binding.

If there is way to get it to work with WCF-WSHTTP, I would still like to know.